# How to mock services in directive tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

i have a directive with the injected apiService which is a wrapper around $http and others custom services.

when I try to test the directive, I don't know how to mock the service:

```
app.directive('coreMenu', ['apiService', function (apiService) {
return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    replace     : true,
    templateUrl : 'Directives/CoreMenu.tpl.html',
    link: function (scope) {
        apiService.get({
            module: 'Core',
            route: 'Menu'
        }).then(function (response) {
            scope.menuItems = response.data;
        }, function (response) {
            // error: no menu available
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Test:

```
describe('coreMenu directive', function() {
var $compile, $rootScope;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('AdminTechPortal');
    module('CoreLeftMenu.tpl.html');

    inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile     = _$compile_;
        $rootScope   = _$rootScope_;
    });

it('replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    var element = $compile("<core-menu></core-menu>")($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(element.html()).toContain('id="core-menu"');
   });
});
```

This test throws ( which is normal):

> Error: Unexpected request: GET /Core/Menu/

Is it possible to mock apiService and not just the xhr call using $httpbackend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in such cases follows... Bear in mind that testing promises (this way) has a bit of work and will fail if the promise needs to be chained!

```
describe('coreMenu directive', function() {
    var $compile, $rootScope, apiServiceMock;

    // BIG WARNING:
    // This beforeEach() block MUST run before using any inject()
    beforeEach(function () {
        apiServiceMock = {};

        apiServiceMock.get = jasmine.createSpy('apiServiceMock.get').and.callFake(function() {
            return { // mock the promise
                then: function(successCb, errorCb) {
                    // keep the callbacks to call them at our convenience
                    apiServiceMock._successCb = successCb;
                    apiServiceMock._errorCb = errorCb;
                }
            };
        });

        module(function($provide) {
            // override the apiService in the DI container
            $provide.value('apiService', apiServiceMock);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('AdminTechPortal');
        module('CoreLeftMenu.tpl.html');

        inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
            $compile     = _$compile_;
            $rootScope   = _$rootScope_;
        });
    });

    it('replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
        var element = $compile("<core-menu></core-menu>")($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();

        // SAMPLE TESTS
        expect(apiServiceMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
        // test success
        apiServiceMock._successCb(...);
        expect(...) // things to expect on success
        // test failure - probably in another it()
        apiServiceMock._errorCb(...);
        expect(...) // things to expect on error
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. add $httpBackend variable:

> ```
> var $compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend;
> ```

2. Inject and assign on beforeEach

> ```
> inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
>     $compile     = _$compile_;
>     $rootScope   = _$rootScope_;
>     $httpBackend   = _$httpBackend_;
> });
> ```

3. Create an afterEach

> ```
> afterEach(function() {
>     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
>     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
> });
> ```

4. test

> ```
> it('replaces the element with the appropriate content', function() {
>     $httpBackend.expectGET('/Core/Menu/');
>     var element = $compile("<core-menu></core-menu>")($rootScope);
>     $httpBackend.flush();
>     $rootScope.$digest(); // Not sure if still needed
>     expect(element.html()).toContain('id="core-menu"');
> });
> ```